`@` in minted SHACL/SPARQL listing introduces an unwanted hyperlink
I want to display a SHACL listing in my paper. It seems that there is no dedicated SHACL lexer but the SPARQL lexer is fine for my purposes. However, for some reason, the @ symbol at the start of my code (@prefix) introduces a hyperlink. Apparently, this hyperlink does not point to anything. How can I remove the hyperlink?
Example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}
    \begin{minted}
    [frame=lines,
    xleftmargin=20pt,
    framesep=2mm,
    baselinestretch=1,
    breaklines,
    tabsize=3,
    fontsize=\scriptsize,
    linenos]{sparql}
@prefix ...
...
    \end{minted}
\end{listing}

\end{document}

Result:


Are you sure, it is a hyperlink? Your document does not use hyperref, so I don't think it is a hyperlink. If I look into the generated code this is just a \PYG{err}{@}.

@cabohah Oh, okay. I see. The problem is that there is no dedicated SHACL lexer but I am somewhat okay with the SPARQL lexer. Can I skip the @prefix line so that the error will disappear?

This is not a hyperlink but the mark of a lexer error. If you have a look into the generated *.pygtex file you will find:
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\PYG{err}{@}\PYG{k}{prefix} \PYG{p}{...}
\PYG{p}{...}
\end{Verbatim}

The \PYG{err}{…} marks lexer errors. If you don't want this, use option ignorelexererrors=true:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}
    \begin{minted}
    [frame=lines,
    xleftmargin=20pt,
    framesep=2mm,
    baselinestretch=1,
    breaklines,
    tabsize=3,
    fontsize=\scriptsize,
    linenos,
    ignorelexererrors=true,
    ]{sparql}
@prefix ...
...
    \end{minted}
\end{listing}

\end{document}


Or if you don't want the first line to be shown, you can use firstline=2:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}
    \begin{minted}
    [frame=lines,
    xleftmargin=20pt,
    framesep=2mm,
    baselinestretch=1,
    breaklines,
    tabsize=3,
    fontsize=\scriptsize,
    linenos,
    firstline=2,
    ]{sparql}
@prefix ...
...
    \end{minted}
\end{listing}

\end{document}


and if the invisible lines should not be numbered, you can additionally add firstnumber=1:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}
    \begin{minted}
    [frame=lines,
    xleftmargin=20pt,
    framesep=2mm,
    baselinestretch=1,
    breaklines,
    tabsize=3,
    fontsize=\scriptsize,
    linenos,
    firstline=2,
    firstnumber=1,% despite the first shown line is line 2, number it 1
    ]{sparql}
@prefix ...
...
    \end{minted}
\end{listing}

\end{document}



Hi, thanks a lot for your help. Yes, I do want to ignore lexer errors. However, unfortunately, I get the following compile error: Package xkeyval Error: `ignorelexererrors' undefined in families `minted@opt@cmd'. Any idea how I can fix this?

@JohnDoe The option is new in minted version 2.9 with date 2023/12/18. So IMHO your minted is too old and needs an update. Depending on the TeX distribution use either the MiKTeX Console or tlmgr to search for updates and install at least this one.

Thanks a lot. After updating minted I got the following error: LaTeX Error: Environment Verbatim undefined. However, updating also fvextra fixed it.
